# Parameterless constructor in c#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oop, c#-4.0

I am writing unit test for an existing class "Person" in Visual studio 2012 and the class has constructor with 2 parameters and some business logic.

```
TestMethod()        
public void VerifyPersonTest()
{
    //Using PrivateObject class
    PrivateObject privateHelperObject = new PrivateObject(typeof(Person));

    //Some business logic                            

}
```

When I try to run above test got an exception **"System.MissingMethodException {"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."}"**.So I have added parameterless constructor to the person class and able to run the test without any issue.

I have following questions

1)As I have added parameterless constructor to the person class ,Will it break any existing functionality of Person class?

2) PrivateObject privateHelperObject = new PrivateObject(typeof(Person));

The above statement invokes parameterless constructor of the person class.Suppose if I want to invoke constructor with 2 parameters,how can I write above statement?

Comment: `new PrivateObject(typeof(Person));` does not invoke the parameterless constructor of class `Person`. You are creating an instance of `PrivateObject` via constructor that takes a `Type`. It does not take an instance of `Person`.

Comment: MissingMethodException means something very different.  You are not running the same code that you compiled against.  A DLL Hell problem.  You probably fixed it by adding this constructor and rebuilding the DLL.  The fix was rebuilding it, not adding the constructor.  So you'd better remove it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could also instantiate the `Person` object yourself:

```
var myPerson = ...;
var privateHelperObject = new PrivateObject(myPerson);
```